# z3py: how to ask which constructor my adt instance has?

Tags: python, z3py

Suppose I have a datatype, for example:

```
List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('cons', ('car', IntSort()), ('cdr', List))
List.declare('nil')
List = List.create()
```

And I have an instance, by:

```
s.check()
instance = s.model()[var]
```

How can i ask which constructor my instance has?
I know I could do something like this:

```
for i in range(List.num_constructors()):
    if List.recognizer(i)(instance):
        break
return List.constructor(i)
```

But this is not a very practical way when the number of constructors is large.
How can i ask this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python interface defines recognizers `is_cons`, `is_nil` for you, which you can then use for simplifying your code. Something like:

```
from z3 import *

List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('cons', ('car', IntSort()), ('cdr', List))
List.declare('nil')
List = List.create()

# constructors
cons = List.cons
car  = List.car
cdr  = List.cdr
nil  = List.nil

# recognizers
def is_cons (x): return simplify(List.is_cons(x))
def is_nil  (x): return simplify(List.is_nil(x))

def valToConstructor(l):
    if is_cons(l):
        return "Found cons"
    elif is_nil(l):
        return "Found nil"
    else:
        raise Exception('Unexpected list value: {}'.format(l))

# example:
ex1 = nil
ex2 = cons (0, cons (1, ex1))

print valToConstructor(ex1)
print valToConstructor(ex2)
```

When run, this produces:

```
Found nil
Found cons
```

Note that you *cannot* skip the exception case in `valToConstructor` since this function might be called with a symbolic value as well; and the recognizers would not fire for those values. But if you always call it with values you get out of a model, it should work just fine.

### Directly accessing the constructor

You can also use the `decl` function for the underlying AST:

```
>>> ex1.decl()
nil
>>> ex2.decl()
cons
```

But you have to be careful when the object you're passing is a symbolic value; as in that case `decl` returns its name:

```
>>> ex3 = Const('ex3_name', List)
>>> ex3.decl()
ex3_name
```

But perhaps this is precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question was specifically how to avoid iterating over all constructors, in case the amount of constructors is large. Your function, valToConstructor, still iterates over all constructors. Is there simply no other way?

Comment: I don’t see any other way of doing it. What would your “ideal” solution look like?

Comment: I am not sure what data structure is used at the background to implement an SMT ADT. But normally I would expect from an instance that I could ask it: "what constructor do you use?", and that it answers in O(1). So something like: instance.get_constructor_index() returns 1, or instance.get_constructor() returns 'cons'

Comment: See my updated answer with the `decl` function. But beware; it is a mere syntactic device to look inside the AST representation; but looks like that's what you are after.